# In Angular4, Array from .subscribe is empty in component.ts

Tags: php, json, angular, api, http

I am fetching data from PHP API, But the variable after subscribe is empty in component.ts but, while using in component.html it displays data. I want to modify after fetching from API.

**In service.ts:**

```
get_tournaments(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost/Website/api/tournament/read.php")
    .map(res=>res.json());
  }
```

**In component.ts:**

```
tournaments:Object[] = [];

ngOnInit() {  
    this.ongoing_ser.get_tournaments() 
    .subscribe(value=>this.tournaments=value);
    console.log("Main:",this.tournaments); <-- this is empty
}
```

**In component.html:**

```
it displays everything correct as required.
```

I want to modify the data fetched from API and then display in html

Answer (score 1):

@Sudhindra Purohit
Javascript is synchronous so it will to wait to complete subscribe your request. So that It will return empty in console.

If you want to modify your data then  you can do like below

```
 this.ongoing_ser.get_tournaments() 
    .subscribe(value=> { this.tournaments=value;
     // DO here what ever you want with tournaments
     this.tournaments = this.tournaments.map(tour => {
       console.log(tour);
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the value to the component variable and then alter it or display it using interpolation {{}}

In the componenet.ts

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.ongoing_ser.get_tournaments() 
        .subscribe(
            (data:any)=>{
                this.data=data;
                //you can do the data modification here 
            })

  }
```

In component.html

```
<div>{{data}}</div>
```

This will display the data in HTML